# Node.js App Datetime stored in Mysql is ahead of UTC time

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

Columns definition :

```
`local_punched_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`punched_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
```

We have an application that is used in multiple timezones, so we are storing UTC time in the punched_at column and the user local time in the local_punched_at column.

When we persist these dates in MySQL the local_punched_at is stored as the same value as punched_at(even we passed the user's local time which is always lower than UTC) or sometimes it is stored value as 1 hour ahead of punched_at value.

For example : For user in America/Chicago Timezone, we send local_punched_at as "2021-11-03 08:52:14" and punched_at : "2021-11-03 13:52:14" , but the DB stored it as
local_punched_at : "2021-11-03 14:52:14" and punched_at : "2021-11-03 13:52:14"

The problem is why the local_punched_at date is changed during saving in MySQL.

MySQL server timezone is UTC.

Node app is running on AWS EC2 and DB is Aurora MySQL.

Did anyone face such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

The `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` data types handle time zones differently in MySQL. You are running into that problem.

`TIMESTAMP` values, when stored, are always translated from the current timezone setting to UTC.  And, when retrieved and sent to a client, they are always translated back to the current timezone setting. Functions like `NOW()` and `CURDATE()` also obey the current timezone setting.

You can set the timezone, for each connection, with `SET time_zone='America/Chicago';`. And you can retrieve the current setting with `SELECT @@time_zone;`

On the other hand, the `DATETIME` data type attempts no translation. It stores whatever you give it verbatim.

Many global applications ask users to set their preferred time zones, with values like `'America/Chicago`' and `'Asia/Kolkata'` and so forth.  Then, when the application connects to the database on behalf of a user it does the `SET time_zone` operation. It's a cool feature, for timestamps that lie within the range of UNIX timestamps.

The global application stores timezone-sensitive data (like the scheduled time for a phone call) in `TIMESTAMP` columns. This allows each user to see times in their local time zone, even when daylight-time changeover days are different between jurisdictions. Like now: England has switched to standard time, but US has not yet. It's based on the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority's wonderful [zoneinfo](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) database.

Your confusion here? It's possible your database connection's time_zone setting defaults to '`America/New_York`' or `'-04:00'`. It seems likely your server is located in the US-East region (in the suburbs of DC) of your cloud provider.  The time_zone setting does not have to be the same as the server's clock.

If you want to always speak UTC to TIMESTAMP data, use `SET time_zone='UTC';` immediately when you open each database connection.

Comment: Your solution worked, Thank you so much. You saved me.